# Library for calculating mfcc vectors

Tags: java, android, mfcc

hi  I am write a small application for android, library needed to calculate mfcc vectors. There are no such library?
it is desirable that the input it takes a byte array, and in return receive the already standard 13 vectors. just all the libraries that I found takes a strange thing that, for me as a newcomer to this field, is not yet clear.

please do not close the question, can you have your achievements and you are willing to share them)

forgot to specify it must necessarily be written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Check out - [Sphinx by CMU](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/develop)

It's completely written in Java. It also has a light-weight version for android.
I've used it in one of my projects - [VoiceMapper](https://github.com/GauthamBanasandra/VoiceMapper/tree/master/src)

It simply takes in audio files as inputs and gives out the corresponding MFCC vectors as output.

To run the program, supply the list of audio files as command line arguments while running the Java program.